# Symfony authentication event that fires only once?

Tags: php, symfony, jwt, symfony-security

I want to log logins.

But both `InteractiveLogin` and `AuthenticationSuccess` events fire on each request (because we use JWT to authenticate, which is passed as a header with every request), and the frontend does the redirection after a successful `/api/login` call, there is no way for me to know, whether the user **just** logged in.

How would you approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a stateless firewall, as is the case when using JWT, the classic `InteractiveLogin` and `AuthenticationSuccess` are useless for this.

What you want to log is **when the token is actually generated**.

If you are using [lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle), you could listen for a `JWTCreatedEvent` event to register that a user logged in.

```
class JwtCreatedSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
 public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            'lexik_jwt_authentication.on_jwt_created' => 'onJwtCreated'
        ];
    }

    public function onJwtCreated(JWTCreatedEvent $event): void
    {
        $user = $event->getUser();
        // record your "last logged-in" according depending on your application set-up

    }
}
```

If you are **not** using this bundle, well, it depends how you are generating your tokens in the first place. But the basic idea would be the same: check for token generation and log **that** time.

A caveat to take into account: if you are using any kind of "token refresh" to maintain sessions without needing to log-in again, each time you refresh the session you would generate a new token... and register a new log-in time.

Comment: This project is more ancient than lexik, so I had no events to work with, but I managed to override the default token manager and inject my logging to where the token was created. Thanks for the idea.